# trigger actualizar stock

Tags: mysql, trigger

Buenos días espero me puedan a ayudar a formular este trigger  para la actualización del stock, después de que el usuario pago los productos con paypal se deberían descontar el numero de  productos adquiridos.
tengo 3 tablas:

en esta tabla se agregan los productos que el cliente agrego junto a su sesión creada
[image: en esta tabla se agregan los productos que el cliente agrego junto a su sesión creada]

En esta tabla se guarda la sesion del usuario y el estado de la compra
[image: En esta tabla se guarda la sesion del usuario y el estado de la compra]

se guardan los datos del cliente tras haber pagado con paypal

[image: se guardan los datos del cliente]

pensaba hacerla mas o menos asi

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockShopping AFTER INSERT ON detalleingreso
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - new.
        WHERE productos.idProducto = new.idarticulo;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

pero no se como debería estructurar el trigger teniendo en cuenta estas tres tablas y mi tabla de productos que cuenta con un campo stock espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Buenas, en que momento quieres descontar el stock cuando el estado de compra este aprobado no?

Comment: exacto eso es lo que necesito podria ayudarme con su aporte por favor

Answer (score 1):

Bueno te paso un ejemplo a lo que pides segun los datos que otorgaste.

```
create trigger CompraEstado_AFTER_UPDATE
    after UPDATE
    on CompraEstado
    for each row
BEGIN
    declare _ItemId varchar(30);
    declare _CantidadCompra double;
    declare _CantidadDescontar double;
    declare _Stock double;
    declare _msg  VARCHAR(100);
    declare cur1 cursor for
          select i.ItemId, i.CantidadCompra
          from DetalleIngreso i
          where i.id = new.id;
    declare CONTINUE  HANDLER FOR  NOT FOUND  SET @fin = 1;

    if new.Status = 'aprovado' and old.Status = 'incompleted'
      then
        set @fin = null;
        open cur1;
        loop1: LOOP
          fetch cur1 into _ItemId,_CantidadCompra;
          IF @fin THEN
            close cur1;
            LEAVE loop1;
          END IF;

          set _CantidadDescontar = _CantidadCompra;
              SELECT Stock
              INTO _Stock
              FROM productos WHERE id=_ItemId;
              IF (_Stock - _CantidadDescontar) >= 0
                THEN
                  UPDATE productos SET Stock=Stock-_CantidadDescontar WHERE id=_ItemId;
              ELSE
                SELECT CONCAT('1- No hay suficiente Stock para el Articulo : ', _ItemId) INTO _msg;
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _msg, MYSQL_ERRNO = 1644;
              END IF;
        END LOOP loop1;
    END IF;
    if old.Status = 'aprovado' and new.Status = 'incompleted'
      then
       #aqui debes reversar la operacion en caso que en tu sistema permita
    END IF;
    if new.Invalid = 'si' and old.Status = 'aprovado'
      then
       #esto es una anulacion, aqui debes reversar la operacion en caso que en tu sistema permita
    END IF;
END;
```

Te agregue cosas como validar si tiene existencia, tambien que tenga en cuenta una desaprobacion e invalidacion.

**Porque el trigger es AFTER_UPDATE?**
Entiendo que el primer estado cuando creas tu registro es 'incompleted' y luego cuando pase a 'aprovado' se actualiza el stock.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad se lo agradezco